# Information of process that has allocated a given Physical address?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I am debugging a kernel memory corruption issue. From the resources i have i am able to find that an address(physical) 03a08000(keeps varying everytime), virtual - c3a08000 is being overwritten.

Now i want to know the process that has allocated this memory. How can i do this?

In short my question is, How can i find the name(process ID or any information) of a process that has allocated a given physical address?

Please let me know in case i am not clear on my question.

Edit : Forgot to mention that i have the complete memory dump(Complete 2 gb ram) with me

Comment: So the physical address that is "corrupted" "keeps varying everytime", but is the virtual address the same?

Comment: @sawdust I believe the op is providing an example virtual address and does not intend to imply that they are always getting the same virt-->phys mapping.  The "corruption" is being caused by some unknown application.

Comment: @Manty well as you are probably aware, the virtual address you cite appears to be a kernel address which means that whatever is "corrupting" your data is in the kernel.  If you can pinpoint the code or module that accesses this memory you may be able to determine the process that caused those changes with a few strategic printk() statements.

Comment: @sawdust The virual address also keeps varying.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Yes i understand that it is in kernel space. Please note that this is not reproducible everytime. I confirmed that the memory is not being over written by linux. It is illegally being accessed from outside by other modules(wireless subsystem), through DMA. So currently i have the ramdump collected after this malfunction. So i dont want to know details of process overwriting it. I did some testing and got the PC value luckily. I wanted to know the process that created the address(using kmalloc etc..) that is getting corrupted. I am using opensource crash tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command called `showmap` inside crash tool. This will tell the exact pid and all the memory that is used by that process aswell.
This is the exact information i was looking for.

`Kmem` shows still better statistics about the details of the related process.

```
crash > kmem <address>
```

Answer (score 2):

By the [PageMap tools](http://www.eqware.net/Articles/CapturingProcessMemoryUsageUnderLinux/) we can map the all the processes in the memory.The PageMap tools consists of two separate command-line utilities:

page-collect.c — Collects the memory “snapshot”; runs on the target platform.
  page-analyze.cpp — Analyzes the memory “snapshot” and generates reports; runs on any platform.

EDIT------

To Debug the crash dump it can be done with [gdb](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/02/debug-kernel-panics-with-crash/) and other [tools](http://d3s.mff.cuni.cz/teaching/crash_dump_analysis/slides/12-linux.pdf). To analyse as quick overview crash [dump](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/08/15/a-quick-overview-of-linux-kernel-crash-dump-analysis/) and [other](http://seife.kernalert.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/linuxtag-2012-crashdump-seyfried.pdf). Complete tutorial on crash [dump.](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html)

RE-EDIT...................................
I am not too sure about your question but when we are analysing [crash dump](http://seife.kernalert.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/linuxtag-2012-crashdump-seyfried.pdf); it starts as

```
linux:/var/crash/20111222 # crash System.map-2.6.32.49-0.3-default \
vmlinux-2.6.32.49-0.3-default.gz vmcore
```

Then we can list all process by `ps` which also shows the `PID` & `Physical Address` both.

Comment: The information is very useful. Thank you for that. But currently i already have a ramdump with me. My context is not a running system. I have a crash dump which i want to investigate. Neverthless the information you provided is very useful. I will make these changes and try to reproduce the crash. I would appreciate if you can suggest some way to debug a crash dump instead of a live system.

Comment: I had edited some links regarding crash dump; hope they may help you.

Comment: Hi @jhonnash I am already using the same crash tool with some added features from my origanization side. But i am not able to see any helpful command which tells me the process name of a physical address.

Comment: These *.ppt may help you. In this in lcrash there is command t Physical Address    ..!!!!https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CHIQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoss.in%2Fslides%2Flb2004%2FLKCD-Linux_Kernel_Crash_Dump_New.ppt&ei=IAHdUYK5KM3irAfwmoHYDw&usg=AFQjCNEvvXgJHqBw2aCGktGqC-D5VPVreQ&sig2=X2VgiS0K_MRun_LqnzLRdw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk

Comment: Are you talking abt vtop command? It gives virtual to physcial address conversion. Not the process associated with it. But these documents are very helpful. +1

Comment: Yes; that also but in document example outputs in last in which `task` and `t <physical address>` used. I think it'll be useful for you.

Comment: Yes that address is the address of the task_struct of that process. task command will print the complete structure along with its members. So i can find the PC and SP values of this process. Not sure if complete physical addresses are printed out where and all the memory is allocated for this process. Will check it.